NavigationViewModel gets unexpectedly cleared when a screen is popped from the back stack
Let's assume I have two screens:

Screen A
Screen B.

When I send a NavigationUiEvent.ShowScreenB to the  NavigationModel, the NavigationModel emits that event into a SharedFlow.
That flow is collected via collectAsStateWithLifecycle in a Navigator composable function. Then that Navigator uses the NavHostController to navigate.
If I hit the back button, the app pops Screen B and I am back to Screen A.
Strangely, NavigationModel#onCleared is invoked during the popping. I picked that stack trace manually:
com.myapp.presentation.viewmodels.NavigationViewModel.onCleared(NavigationViewModel.kt:59)
androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel.clear(ViewModel.java:202)
androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelStore.clear(ViewModelStore.kt:69)
androidx.navigation.NavControllerViewModel.clear(NavControllerViewModel.kt:33)
androidx.navigation.NavController$NavControllerNavigatorState.markTransitionComplete(NavController.kt:359)
androidx.navigation.compose.ComposeNavigator.onTransitionComplete(ComposeNavigator.kt:8androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$15.invokeSuspend(NavHost.kt:314)

Because of this, the NavigationViewModel scope & flow are cancelled, and won't accept any new NavigationUiEvent whatsoever so I am stuck at Screen A.

Please have a look at my code ⤵️
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyAppTheme {
                Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                        SetupAppNavigation()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun SetupAppNavigation() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()

    Navigator(navHostController = navController) // sits on top of the nav host

    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = "screen_a",
    ) {
        composable(route = "screen_a") {
            ScreenARoute()
        }

        composable(route = "screen_b") {
            ScreenBRoute()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Navigator(
    navHostController: NavHostController,
) {
    val navigationViewModel: NavigationViewModel = koinViewModel()
    val navDirection: NavigationUiEvent? by navigationViewModel.state.collectAsStateWithLifecycle(initialValue = null)

    when (val nav = navDirection) {
        is NavigationUiEvent.ScreenB -> navHostController.navigate(route = "screen_b")
        null -> Unit // Nothing to do here
    }
}

class NavigationViewModel internal constructor() : ViewModel(), NavigationUiEventHandler, KoinComponent {

    private val module: Module by lazy {
        module {
            single { this@NavigationViewModel } bind NavigationUiEventHandler::class
        }
    }

    private val events = MutableSharedFlow<NavigationUiEvent>()

    val state: SharedFlow<NavigationUiEvent> = events
        .onStart { getKoin().loadModules(listOf(module)) }
        .onCompletion { getKoin().unloadModules(listOf(module)) }
        .shareIn(
            scope = viewModelScope,
            started = SharingStarted.Eagerly,
        )

    override fun handleEvent(event: NavigationUiEvent) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            events.emit(event)
        }
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        println("DEBUG >> NavigationViewModel CLEARED so YEAH GOODBYE !")
    }
}


# KOIN INJECTION #

val viewModelsModule = module {
    viewModeOf(::NavigationViewModel)
    viewModeOf(::ScreenAViewModel)
    viewModeOf(::ScreenBViewModel)
}

class MyApp: Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        startKoin {
            androidLogger()
            androidContext(this@ MyApp)
            modules(
                listOf(
                    viewModelsModule,
                    ...
                )
            )
        }
    }
}

The app prints...
DEBUG >> NavigationViewModel CLEARED so YEAH GOODBYE !

... when I am going back to Screen A.
Why ?
I honestly don't understand why NavControllerViewModel (from the stack trace) would clear my NavigationViewModel even though it isn't explicitly scoped to a particular screen as part of my navigation graph.

Do you access NavigationViewModel inside ScreenBRoute()? Please include that code.

@ianhanniballake  Ah! You've got a point. ScreenBRoute does reference the same instance of NavigationViewModel in order to send a GoBack Nav event (I did not mention to keep my OP concise) when user hits the back button from the scaffold : val navViewModel: NavigationViewModel = koinViewModel() and then TopAppBar > navigationIcon > IconButton#OnClick = { navViewModel.handleEvent(event = NavigationUiEvent.GoBack) }. Why does it matter ? I don't get it  Thanks !

Ok, so I removed any reference of the NavigationViewModel  in ScreenBRoute and I use the android back button to go back and this what happens. The NavigationViewModel no longer gets cleared. Upon back, new nav events can be successfully emitted. I'd like to understand why referencing the NavigationViewModel in navigation graph's screens could be the issue ?

If you put log statements in your ViewModel's init and onCleared that print out this, do you see two separate instances or just one instance?

@ianhanniballake I see only one instance. The instance is still alive when attempting to handle new nav events, so that could be a sort of leak.
Anyway, the logs are  crystal clear: my app creates a single instance of my NavigationViewModel (as expected because it handles the whole app navigation) and the app clears it as soon as a screen that uses it is popped from the back stack.
